# Angularjs model won't update after query from pouchdb

Tags: angularjs, pouchdb

I'm writting an angularjs app with PouchDB. I can't get updated template after query from db.
I loaded data from XML2JSON, then put them to pouchdb. Here is the deal.

If I use this to fill data to view, every think is OK.

```
  $http.get('Katalog_27_11_2014_21_41_21.xml').then(function(resp) {
  console.log(resp);
  return resp.data;
}).then(function(string) {
  var jsonData = xmlParser.xml_str2json(string);
  var outPutJSON = [];
  console.log(jsonData);
  angular.forEach(jsonData.Catalog.Item, function(value, key) {
    Database.put(value.EANs.EAN,value);
    outPutJSON.push(value);
    console.log(value);
  });

  $scope.products = outPutJSON;
});
```

but if I use query from pouchdb the view is empty, I see the data in console nad even in the ng-inspector, but not in the view. I thougth that I have to user  $scope.apply() for updating the view and model, but that's what i get TypeError: undefined is not a function {stack: (...), message: "undefined is not a function"} 
The  in view is empty. I can't figure out where is the bug... :]

```
  Database.queryDocs().then(function(doc) {
  var _products = [];
  log.debug(doc);
  angular.forEach(doc.rows, function(value, key) {
    log.debug(value);
    _products.push(value.doc.data);
  });
  $scope.products = _products;
  // $scope.apply();
  log.debug($scope.products);
})
.catch(function(argument) {
  log.debug(argument);
});
```

UPDATE

I've added this, now it's magicly works, but still don't know why. Becouse I'm using the same in other app (Ionic) and there is working - angular 1.2.7. I'm confused. Here is 1.3.4

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
    $scope.products = _products;
  })
```

Comment: You've spelled $apply() incorrectly - is that the problem maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The digest cycle is run using $scope.$apply(), not $scope.aplly().

Comment: Yep, that's it $scope.$apply(), I wrote $scope.apply()  Now its working. :D Thx

Answer (score 0):

That was typping error here. I'm using $scope.apply();

Comment: Have you got the dollar sign in front of apply? $apply(), not apply() ?